# Is TreeView supported on Uno Platform?

Tags: c#, xaml, treeview, winui-3, uno-platform

I have a WinUI3 app running on Uno Platform and I'm trying to implement a TreeView.
I've tried several examples that I've found on the internet but no one has worked well. The only one that has compiled is the one from the unoplatform github: [https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/SamplesApp/UITests.Shared/Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls/TreeView/TreeViewBasics.xaml](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Here we can see the xaml and cs code:

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UITests.Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls.TreeView.TreeViewBasics"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:UITests.Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls.TreeView"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <muxc:TreeView>
            <muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode x:Name="RootNode" Content="Flavors" IsExpanded="True">
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla" />
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry" />
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Chocolate">
                            <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Dark" />
                                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="White" />
                            </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                        </muxc:TreeViewNode>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Caramel" />
                    </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                </muxc:TreeViewNode>
            </muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
        </muxc:TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

cs:

```
using Uno.UI.Samples.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace UITests.Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls.TreeView
{
    [Sample("TreeView")]
    public sealed partial class TreeViewBasics : Page
    {
        public TreeViewBasics()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();         
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'd really like to know if anyone is able to use this code correctly and if it works fine. When I run it it desn't appear anything.

I've also observed that here they use Uno.UI.Samples.Controls and I'm worried that might be the source of my problems, but I cannot use it since I actually use Uno.WinUI and if I istall both nugget packages vs complains about it.

I'd be very glad if someone could respond some of my doubts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TreeView is shown on the Uno Platform Playground:
https://playground.platform.uno/#treeview

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however as I already said the one from the Uno Playground does not work. And id that sample there is not any unimplemented feature, the there should not be any problem there. I'll keep looking for a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Raj2001 it seems they've now fixed those issues.